# Maven -Standard

Tags: maven, svn

i would like to work with Maven after we used ANT.

i have few questions:

1. As per my understanding it is much easier to work with Maven if i will have a common structure directory layout and therefore i will be able to build this and other project more easily. what is the standard and how you recommend to perform it?
2. I have few sub-applications and many modules under each of them . 
   Assuming our application named A1,A2,A3,A4, and using SVN (from scratch) as our source control. do you recommend putting the name of the application as a prefix in SVN so it will be built easier? 
   @scm.it.att.com: port \ **A1** \ (branches,trunk,tags)\ or **without the A1** .// in order to have fluent build with Maven.
3. which one are recommended?
   `@scm.it.att.com:port \<release_name>\branches\module` or `@scm.it.att.com:<port>\branches\module\<release_name>`
   in terms of building it with Maven standards. we need to build only a specific module and not the entire repo.

Comment: 1. Google for "standard Mavan project layout" and read. It's documented, and documentation exists for a reason. 2. Maven doesnt care about your SCM (but I would never start using SVN. Git is sooo much better, and sooo much more popular). 3. The two options are identical, soI don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: 3. If you have to build a single module that this should be a separate project and having a separate repository (Git). The only question which is important: Which modules should be released together ? Those should be located into a single repository and should be a multi module build. Can you please show more in detail what you have in mind based on 2. cause I really don't understand what you have in mind? make an example project as best and put it somewhere so we take a look...

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the input, for question 3,clarification- 
of course the question is which are a better method-

svn:.../ module_name /branches/release_name

or

svn:.../ branches/ release/ module_name( list of all the modules within the same release) /

at the first option , each module show under his branches what are the releases it was part of and allow to go to that specific source code for a specific release comparing the second module which contains-  under one release,  all the modules  built in that release. and then you can peek one module and see the source code.

the question is : what is the best way to implement&organize it in the SVN in terms of intuitive Maven build?

thanks !!!